# Amazon S3 image CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I am using amazon cloudfront for CDN. can someone please tell me why i am still not able to see Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"?

**MY S3 cors**

[image]

Comment: Did you invalidate the cache after setting up CORS?  Did you whitelist the `Origin` and other CORS request headers in the CloudFront Cache Behavior?

Comment: Perhaps your screen shot has clipped the LHS of the config file because otherwise it looks invalid. Are you receiving only GET requests?

Comment: Michael-sqlbot :  i have whitelisted Origin and other headers . still same issue is coming. CORS not aalowed.

Comment: @mhawke yes i am receiving only get Request.But CORS not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my setup, you need both edit the CORS in S3 as well in the CloudFront

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I don't know if it's part of the protocol, but it's the only way I could set up for a CORS call

**you also need** to whitelist the `Origin` of your CDN behavior

like:

[image]

Comment: Still same issue.
when i test in online CORS checking, response is like this
"Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: progress
Fired XHR event: error

XHR status: 0
XHR status text: 
Fired XHR event: loadend"

Comment: @Venkatesh no idea what are you talking about, but do a simple test, go to jQuery homepage and execute `$.get(url,(d)=>{console.log(d);});` and set up `var url = '';` with a **text file** url of the CDN you are testing.

Answer (score 19):

I'm writing this answer cause I was stuck in the issue for almost a day.

## Add CORS permission on AWS S3

1. Open the specific bucket.
2. Then click on the permission tab on the top
   [image]
3. Then scroll to the last, and you will find the CORS configuration. Just click on edit.
   [image]
4. Then paste the below configuration in

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

5. You can also add your custom domains inside AllowedOrigin

## Remove cache from API call

I have done the above change but still, I was facing the same issue again and again. I fixed that by disabling the cache of the API. I was using `fetch` to call the s3 URL. Below is the code for it.

```
fetch(
    <s3 URL>,
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { "Cache-Control": 'no-cache' },
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to set CORS headers in the **Permissions** tab, as mentioned by [Anand Tripathi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67473535/10008746) in the above answer.

But also from the server side, we need to set some headers like below as mentioned in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#functional_overview).

```
  res.header("Vary", "Origin");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get("origin") || req.get("host"));
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
```

the above example is for NodeJs-Express.

The above headers are validated by the browser, by calling the OPTIONS rest API method, so make sure to send them in response.

> Note:- res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") won't work, it'll result in the cors error, so we need to set the exact origin

In my case ( NodeJs-ExpressJs ), I was using like below,

```
const cors = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Vary", "Origin");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get("origin") || req.get("host"));
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
  next();
};

app. use(cors);// as a middleware // the cors headers will be set in every response.
```