# amplify 403 comes up that too with a CORS error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Through Amplify CLI added an API that invokes a lambda that reads the dynamo table.

It worked well y'day after the deployment in AWS. Today morning it 
throws 403 error with no changes being made:

> **GET** https://xxnxxtfxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/items
>   **403**
>
> **Access to XMLHttpRequest** at
>   'https://xxnxxtfxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/items'
>   from origin
>   ''http://myproject-20181130113531--hostingbucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com''
>   **has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.**

**Observations/Actions**

- Ensure CORS is enabled on API Gateway, redeploy the API.
- Testing API is successful from API Gateway, it invokes the Lambda function properly
- Amplify service does create the user object and is persisting in localstorage
- invocation of OPTIONS is looking good as well under developer tools:

  **General Settings:**
- Request URL: https://xxnxxtfxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/items
- Request Method: OPTIONS
- Status Code: 200

  **Response Headers:**
- access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
- access-control-allow-methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
- access-control-allow-origin: *`

**Wondering why would 403 come up that to with a CORS error.** Any thoughts? what baffles and scares me is 
that a few hours after I wake up with no changes things are failing :-(

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73364013/10008746), this works for AWS S3 static hosting, CloudFront, Amplify, and other static website hosting sites.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error (and follow the same actions). In my case, I wasn't passing the correct arguments in the [Amplify post call](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api) by skipping the init argument. I fix this by passing a myInit argument with an empty body:

```
let myInit = {
    body: {}
}

API.post(apiName, path, myInit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/handle-api-gateway-cors-errors.html

The answer is that your response needs a the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the header.

Unfortunately, when your API returns an error, it does not include these values in the header. You need to create a Gateway Response to enable these headers in your error responses.

Hope this helps : )